# Spring data 1.4.3 and enumerations

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using the following stuff:
    - Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE
    - Hibernate 4.3.1.Final
    - Spring data 1.4.3

I can't define a query by enumeration in my repositories.

Here is my entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "HOL_TEST")
public class Test5 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 55741987968716878l;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEST_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ENUM_COLUMN", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private TestEnum testEnum;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TestEnum getTestEnum() {
        return testEnum;
    }

    public void setTestEnum(TestEnum testEnum) {
        this.testEnum = testEnum;
    }

}
```

Here is my Enum:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    A, B
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.jpi.jsff.model.Test5;
import com.jpi.jsff.model.TestEnum;

public interface TestEnumRepository extends JpaRepository<Test5, Long> {

    public List<Test5> findByTestEnum(TestEnum testEnum);

}
```

Here is my test:
p

```
ublic class TestRepository extends IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        Test5 test = new Test5();
        test.setTestEnum(TestEnum.A);

        testEnumRepository.save(test);
        test = new Test5();
        test.setTestEnum(TestEnum.B);

        testEnumRepository.save(test);
        System.out.println(testEnumRepository.findAll().size());
        System.out.println(testEnumRepository.findByTestEnum(TestEnum.A).size());
    }
}
```

This prints 2 and then 0. Showhing that my entities are correctly inserted and found using findAll but that the findByTestEnum is not working...

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jpi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsff2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.source.level>1.7</java.source.level>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <org.spring.data.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</org.spring.data.version>
        <com.sun.faces.version>2.2.5</com.sun.faces.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.primefaces.version>4.0</org.primefaces.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sun.faces.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sun.faces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${org.primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.level}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.level}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes></packagingExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.zeroturnaround
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jrebel-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.1.3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What happens if you perform the findAll test and iterate through the entities checking the enum?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I am using oracle11g. If I make a findAll I find correctly all my entities and my enum is correctly set in my entity!

Comment: I was able to create a working example however I was using different versions of spring and hibernate.  I am using MySQL.  I am also looking to align my versions with yours for testing.  I take it you have a clean stack trace?

Comment: Are you using maven?  Could you post your pom?

Comment: Thanks I am going to use that to make sure we are using the same libraries.  One question, why do you have the oracle driver and the mysql driver?

Comment: Updated my pom file still no issue.  Another thing I noticed was that the test doesn't autowire the repository, is that just omitted?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Don't know I removed them ;). It is in the upper class IntegrationTest

Comment: Here is a Gist with my files: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/8975228  If you would package up your project and make it available I would take a look, but I'm not seeing anything wrong with what you have presented.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Did you manage to make it work with my framekwork versions? I can upload my project unfortunatly :(.

Comment: Yes I did, everything except the database.  Which tells me there is something not shown causing the issue or the db is the issue.